# Splunk query to collect non unique values as comma separated along with group by other columns

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

Splunk query `<my search_criteria> | stats count by Proxy, API, VERB, ClientApp` preparing the below table.

| Proxy | API | VERB | ClientApp | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CUSTOMER_OFFICE_CLIENTS | clients/{clientId} | GET | co_web | 5 |
| CUSTOMER_OFFICE_CLIENTS | clients/{clientId} | GET | co_mobile | 6 |
| CUSTOMER_OFFICE_CLIENTS | clients/{clientId} | GET | co_tab | 4 |
| CUSTOMER_OFFICE_CLIENTS | clients | POST | co_web | 57 |
| CUSTOMER_OFFICE_CLIENTS | clients | POST | co_mobile | 34 |
| CUSTOMER_OFFICE_CLIENTS | clients | POST | co_tab | 50 |

Is there a way to group by Proxy, API, VERB and collect ClientApp values as comma separated list as follows with splunk query?

| Proxy | API | VERB | ClientApp | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CUSTOMER_OFFICE_CLIENTS | clients/{clientId} | GET | co_web, co_mobile, co_tab | 15 |
| CUSTOMER_OFFICE_CLIENTS | clients | POST | co_web, co_mobile, co_tab | 141 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`values()`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.0.1/SearchReference/Multivaluefunctions#values.28X.29) to return all of the unique ClientApp values in each row.

```
| stats values(ClientApp) count by Proxy, API, VERB
```

and to get the ClientApp values in a comma-separated list, use the mvjoin function.

```
| stats values(ClientApp) as ClientApp count by Proxy, API, VERB 
| eval ClientApp = mvjoin(ClientApp, ",")
```

Comment: To get the ClientApp values in a comma-separated list, use the `mvjoin` function.  `| stats values(ClientApp) as ClientApp count by Proxy, API, VERB | eval ClientApp = mvjoin(ClientApp, ",")`.